# How to scrape the HTTP header? (Redirect URL?)

Tags: excel, vba, http, header

I've installed an add-on in my browser which let me see all the HTTP headers that go back and forth from my Firefox and a web server.

This is a simple code I've used:

```
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", "Initial_URL.com", False
WinHttpReq.Send
```

Below is the http header obtained:

```
https://Initial_URL.com
Host: Initial_URL.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
GET: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
content-length: 2361
content-type: text/html

date: Wed, 09 Jan 2019 19:46:06 GMT
location: Redirected_to.com
Set-Cookie: PD-S-SESSION-ID=1_2_0_ud2NmPnh++62VQCPVkwxb8xp0wuMBDhqmfZiqltbPrgksUAf;
```

First part of the header is what the HTTP header has sent to the server, and then the answer from the server.

I need to get some of these fields (e.g. location, Set-Cookie). 
I've parsed the WinHttpReq.ResponseText, but it is pure HTTP code, no headers at all.
Any guidance?

Comment: Run the `getAllResponseHeaders` method after submitting the web request. It should return a string with the header information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the header information, you can get that from the `getAllResponseHeaders` method.

Here is a small demo:

```
Sub GetHeaders()
    Dim headers As String
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118535/excel-vba-how-to-scrape-the-http-header-webserver-answer-redirect-url"
        .send
        headers = .getAllResponseHeaders
        Debug.Print headers
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan, that was exactly what i was looking for!!! Many thanks!!!